# Stream a swf instead of downloading a whole swf before displaying

Tags: streaming, flash

Is there any way to stream an .swf file instead of making the site wait until the entire swf is loaded?  A client i am working for wants a flash-based animation to open the site, but it is a big file.  Was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for swf streaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially swf was designed for some streaming ( playing the content on the fly as available ), the trouble was that it wasn't designed for loading random part of the swf like a "proper" streaming video.
so depending on what your swf is doing you can still stream it, and can use the [framesLoaded](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#framesLoaded) property to figure out if the part you want to play is loaded and wait at regular checkpoint.

Comment: Mostly because there's no way to convert frames or duration into something that a range request can handle.